# Архивация приложения в xCode

Tags: ios, xcode

Как исправить ошибку?
Code Signing Error: "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен provisioning profile для вашего App Extension, так как собираете в Release, то нужен Distribution provisioning profile